# PHPMailer subject with HTML msg

Tags: php, phpmailer

I need to send a email with a HTML msg on the Subject.

For the body, I use `$mail->MsgHTML($someHTML);` and it works fine.

But when I try to do the same with the Subject, it just interpret the whole thing as a text.

What I need is something like this:

```
$subject = "<img src='PATH_TO_IMG_FILE_IN_MY_SERVER'> This is the subject"
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

Already tried to use the `$mail->isHTML(true);` but for what I read, it works only for the email's body.

Comment: No mail client I've ever heard of renders HTML in the subject line. Unicode maybe, but HTML?  No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitively, no. Email doesn't support HTML in the subject line, or any other header.

Comment: After your response I found out that it is possible to send an emoji inside the email's subject just by putting it there with the right encodings. I guess I just needed someone to confirm that send HTML in the subject line is IMPOSSIBLE. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you can do this; all that's needed in PHPMailer to enable it is to set `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'` and you can just use literal unicode chars in your code, including emoji.